# Karate assertions response matching assertions are failing

Tags: karate

```
And match response.error.details[*].message contains <message>
Examples:
  | status | code | programId         | description | id       | type            | message                                                        |
  | 404    | 404  | maxProgramId      | Not Found   | NotFound | validationError | "The value is not found."
```

[image: Cucumber report showing response matching is failing even though they are same text.]

Comment: never use screenshots please: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - follow this process or wait for someone else here to help you: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: Sure i will avoid them in future. But i would like to show the print statements were printing the same texts but the match assertion is failing.

Comment: see the second link above, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try using  get[0] response.error.details[*].message

as response.error.details[*].message returns an array